# xslt transform on hex string

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have to transform my string in a peculiar way, as the string contains many hex values and replacement has to be applied based on some conditions.

My string contains hex values.

Always the length of string, will be a multiple of 18. The string can contain from 1* 18 to 5000*18 times(1 group to 5000 groups).

Now my output is a transformed string based on the below conditions

```
1) Check if the groups 13th character is 4e(13th and 14th character)


  Then, change such a way that starting from 7th to 10th character(4 chars) of the string, from whatever the value is to '4040'


    Also change starting from 11th till 16th(6 chars) to '4ef0f0'
    The 17th and 18th to be '4040'

   The whole group to be changed based on the above


2) If the check fails, no change for the group
```

Example if my input string is - one group and the 12th and 13th are '4e'

```
<xsl:variable name="inputstringhex"
      select="'005f6f7e8f914e7175'"/>
```

It should be tranformed to

```
'005f6f40404ef0f04040'
```

I am using xslt1.0, and I can use only Divide and conquer method(if any recursion is used), as my xslt processor errors out if tail recursive method is used, for a large number.

Comment: If you use binary-log recursion instead of linear recursion, you should be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use binary-log recursion (perhaps that is what you mean by divide and conquer? Any way, this XSLT 1.0 style-sheet...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:variable name="inputstringhex"
      select="'005f6f7e8f914e717512346f7e8f914e7175'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <t>
    <xsl:call-template name="string18s">
      <xsl:with-param name="values" select="$inputstringhex" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </t>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="string18s">
  <xsl:param name="values" />
  <xsl:variable name="value-count" select="string-length($values) div 18" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$value-count = 0" />
    <xsl:when test="$value-count &gt;= 2">
      <xsl:variable name="half-way" select="floor( $value-count div 2) * 18" />
      <xsl:call-template name="string18s">
        <xsl:with-param name="values" select="substring( $values, 1, $half-way)" />
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:call-template name="string18s">
        <xsl:with-param name="values" select="substring( $values,
         $half-way+1, string-length($values) - $half-way)" />
      </xsl:call-template>      
    </xsl:when>  
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:call-template name="process-one-string18">
        <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$values" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>  
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="process-one-string18">
  <xsl:param name="value" />
  <v>
   <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="substring( $value, 13, 2) = '4e'"> 
      <xsl:value-of select="concat( substring( $value, 1, 6),
                                    '40404ef0f04040')" />
    </xsl:when> 
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$value" />
    </xsl:otherwise> 
   </xsl:choose>
  </v>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...will produce this output...

```
<t>
  <v>005f6f40404ef0f04040</v>
  <v>12346f40404ef0f04040</v>
</t>
```

Adapt or concatenate values of the output as required. The input is the $inputstringhex variable content. A 5000*18 length input string can be processed in only 13 levels of recursion using this solution.